# In this website, how do I input Jupyter notebook cells, code, and outputs in the formatting box?

Tags: post, formatting, format, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to post blocks of code coming from the jupyter notebook and want to keep their format, color, ins, outs, and answers just like it shows in the image link below.

(I had to post a link since StackOverflow won't allow me to post a picture
just yet.)

I tried to do it manually just as regular code, but it is time-consuming typing and formatting all the cells, also it won't show the different colors in my lines of code in the preview.

Furthermore, I tried the formatting links given on this site, but didn't see anything related to building jupyter notebook sample code

Similar to the answer given to this question:

[sample answer to a question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PYAe.png)

Comment: Please see the StackOverflow editing help, these is nothing specific to Jupyter Notebook on SO . https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Request for how to use Stack-Overflow itself.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that this is nothing specific to Jupyter Notebook Matt, I appreciate it!